# Uploading csv file with comma and apart in google sheet

Tags: html, csv, google-sheets

My CSV file:

[image: my CSV file]

Google sheet I got is

[image: Google sheet]

My desired Google sheet

[image]

The question is what csv will generate the desired google sheet. Please help me with that.

Thanks in advance.
uv.

Comment: This is not csv but the function syntax of google sheets. CSV stands for comma-separated values which is a text format for storing large amounts of data in tables

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com"; "LINK")
```

[image]

or:

```
="HYPERLINK(""https://www.google.com"",""LINK"")"
```

[image]

---

### update:

try your CSV like:

```
123,=HYPERLINK("google.com";"LINK"),abcd
```

semicolon `;` will be autocorrected to a comma `,` within english sheets after the formula gets activated

so when you import it you will use comma `,` split separator which will either get you exactly what you want or it will look like this:

[image]

eg. without an active link, so you will need to add some character in front of the equal `=` sign:

[image]

and then remove it:

[image]

to automate it you could harness the power of scripts or run some macro

Comment: CSV is "1234,="HYPERLINK(""https://www.google.com"",""LINK"")",abcd" .  In google sheet, B1 cell ="HYPERLINK(""https://www.google.com""  is stored and in C1 cell LINK"")"

Comment: @ActiveHub can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?

Comment: I have edited the description. Please help.

Comment: @ActiveHub answer updated

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with `=HYPERLINK ( "url", "label" )`

Alternatively here’s how you can do that from the Insert menu.

1. Select the cell where you want to insert the hyperlink. You can also
   do this by double-clicking on the cell
2. Go to the Insert menu. Select the Link option from the menu.
3. After clicking on the Link option from the dropdown menu, you will
   get a dialogue box that looks exactly like the one in the above
   image.
4. In the Search and paste a link box, type the link you want to insert
   or you can copy the webpage’s link from the search bar of your
   browser and paste it here.
5. Click on the Apply button.

After you click on Apply, you should see the above pop-up. There are two things you should note here that will serve as a check to know whether or not you’ve done the right thing.

- The anchor text (the text to which the URL or web link is applied)
  will be automatically highlighted in blue. This is how Google sheets
  indicate to users of the data that the character in the cell contains
  a link to an external source.
- There will be a preview of the weblink
  at the bottom of the cell. This is going to be visible if you have
  the cell selected, or you place the cursor on the hyperlinked cell.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  I am creating a csv with the text. 123,=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com","LINK"),abcd.  Uploading the csv in google sheet. Expecting LINK to be a hyperlink in cell 2.

Comment: this link could help https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/change-excel-csv-delimiter/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to insert formulas into a google sheet from a CSV. I cant say I've seen or used CSV this way before, but here are a couple  (untested) things you might be able to try to make this work:

1. **Use something other than a comma as the delimiter**

since it seems like your "data" (i.e. the values you want to put inside each cell) can also possibly include commas, you may want to try changing the delimiter (the character that is used to split the data, which is usually a comma).

I'm not sure if google docs will allow you to easily import this, but maybe using this as your source data this might help:

`1234;=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com", "LINK");abcd` (note that the delimiter between cells is now `;` and not `,`)

If google docs does not allow you to import this, you might be able to try opening it in a program such as Microsoft Excel or [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) this should (at least in libreoffice) present you with a popup box to allow you to change the delimiter and preview the data so you can be sure its reading your CSV correctly. You can then upload the .xlsx or .ods spreadsheet file to google docs and have them convert it to a google doc for you.

This adds a couple extra steps to the import process and may or may not work for whatever you are trying to do.

2. **remove the formula from the data**

My recommendation would be to separate out just the raw data when its in csv format:

`1234,https://www.google.com,LINK,abcd`

this should be much more likely to correctly import directly in google docs. To get the hyperlinks working, you would then need to:

1. create a new column between the "LINK" and "ABCD" columns
2. enter your hyperlink formula in that column using the values from the two columns to the left of it (i.e. `=HYPERLINK(A2,A3)`)
3. drag this formula down to apply to all of your data
4. Hide the two columns containing the parts of the link

This also requires some additional manual work after importing the data, which may or may not suit your usecase depending on the [actual problem you are trying to solve](https://xyproblem.info/)

3. **Adjust the quotes**

It seems like other answers have attempted this method already, but it seems as though the quotes need to be correct for this to work properly. One [source](https://mattzaske.com/blog/2020-08/formulas-csv-files) I found indicates that your data should be quoted like this (note the equals sign is inside the quotes and nested quotes are double-quoted):

`1234,"=HYPERLINK(""https://www.google.com"", ""LINK"")",abcd`

If the quotes are giving you trouble, you could also maybe try a hybrid solution and try something like this:

`1234,https://www.google.com,LINK,"=HYPERLINK(A2,A3)",abcd`